# How to send data from Service to Activity ? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, service

I want to pass data from service to activity from another app. I already did activity to service exactly same as Bound Services using Messenger in developer.android.com. However they didn't do service to activity in Kotlin, and I didn't see similar solution in Kotlin. There are java solutions but they didn't work for me. Probably Messenger or Broadcast should work but I want to know how.

I think activity should have `IncomingHandler` and service should have `onServiceConnected` so can send message like `mService?.send(msg)` , but I didn't find how to bind them.

**Update**
Service

```
val intent = Intent("TO_SALE_APP")
                intent.putExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", responseCode)
                intent.putExtra("STATUS", status)
                intent.putExtra("PAYMENT_TYPE", paymentType)
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.applicationContext).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

**Update**
Activity

```
private val mMessageReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
        val responseCode = intent.getStringExtra("RESPONSE_CODE")
        val status = intent.getIntExtra("STATUS",0)
        val paymentType = intent.getIntExtra("PAYMENT_TYPE",0)
        Log.d("myTAG","data receive on activity!")
    }
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   ...
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
       mMessageReceiver, IntentFilter("TO_SALE_APP")
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send data from Services to Activity
I had done it by sending Location Coordinated from Background Service class to Activity Periodically

In the service, class add this code

```
val intent = Intent("GPSLocationUpdates")
intent.putExtra("latitude", location.latitude.toString())
intent.putExtra("longitude", location.longitude.toString())

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this@LocationService).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

In your Activity receives this data by , write this before `onCreate`

```
private val mMessageReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            val latitude = intent.getStringExtra("latitude")
            val longitude = intent.getStringExtra("longitude")
        }
    }
```

and in the `onCreate` method mention this

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, IntentFilter("GPSLocationUpdates")
        );
```

NOTE: the EventListener GPSLocationUpdates should be the same in Service and Activity

Comment: I updated as you suggest and edited above, but receiver not receive that intent. Should I add any flags for intent or made change on Manifest ? Maybe action not seen in activity app.

Comment: did u mentioned that you have two differents application for service and Activity?

Comment: Yes, in the explanation I said from service to activity from another app, sorry if it was not clear.